# How to design a simple database

Tags: mysql, database

I want to model a student, teacher, class relationship. Every student is associated with one teacher (the teacher can have many students). There are only three classes. The way I think of this is that there are three tables:

Student Table -> (student_id, student_name, class_id)

Teacher Table -> (student_id, student_name, class_id)

Class Table -> (class_id, class_name)

I'm not sure how to show the student-teacher relationship within the tables. How would we know which teacher is assigned to which student?

Comment: You introduce one more "link" table `Student_Teacher`.   Remove `class_id` from both `Student` and `Teacher` and it to the new table.

Comment: Could add another table "assigned_students" and have columns: student_id, teacher_id

Then in your code, just pull / insert into that table who is assigned to who.

Comment: This is an example of `many-to-many` relationship. Student can be taught by many teachers, and teacher can teach many students.  You will need an intermediate table (StudentTeacher maybe) to break the relationship into `one-to-many`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with some simple joins.

Assuming that you want to find all the students associated with a certain teacher, you would start off by grabbing the row for the `teacher`. You would then join in the `classes` that the teacher teaches. Finally, you would join in the `students` that are in those classes.

This is known as a many-to-many relationship, and is an important concept in databases.

```
select
    t.student_name, -- I suspect this col might actually be named teacher_name
    s.student_name, 
from
    -- Find the classes that a teacher teaches
    teacher_table t join class_table c on (t.class_id=c.class_id)
    -- Find the students in those classes
    join student_table s on (s.class_id=c.class_id)
where
    t.student_id = ? -- Again, I suspect this should be "teacher_id"
```

Comment: I should mention that you can join the teacher_table and student_table directly. But I've included the classes table in my answer, as a demonstration of how many-to-many might be achieved in general. If you don't need any data from the classes table (such as "class completion date" for use in a where clause, or something), you could simply use `SELECT t.student_name, s.student_name FROM teacher_table t JOIN student_table s ON (t.class_id=s.class_id) WHERE t.student_id = ?`

Answer (score 1):

This is a few more tables than you want, but several of the .NET examples that Microsoft has created revolve around a similar relational database.

Here is a link to that database:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399731(v=vs.100).aspx

In this example, the student and the teacher are both kept in the person table and are related to the course table through two different Joining tables . . student grade and course instructor.

[image]

And here is the Contoso University Schema with link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

[image]